# HTTP 302 error while accessing web application deployed on Oracle Weblogic 10.3.3

Tags: java, http, weblogic11g

I have deployed war on weblogic with following URL

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6767/em/index.html

My cisco loadbalancer probe following URL

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6767/em

and on getting http 200 response it make status of my servers to active.

But currently weblogic is providing 302 status code.

I am unable to identify why it doing so?

I check above both URL through browser and its working fine.

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HTTP 302 response is **not** an error. Only 4nn (client) and 5nn (server) are errors. A 302 simply means that the response is been redirected to another URL. The webserver is apparently redirecting http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6767/em to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6767/em/ or http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6767/em/index.html.

You just need to let your loadbalancer probe http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6767/em/ or http://xx.xx.xx.xx:6767/em/index.html.

#### See also:

- [HTTP status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply can i do changes on application side? because for changes on loadbalancer i have to call my vendor.

Comment: how about if we deploy servlet and set url pattern to rootcontext?

Comment: Not possible. The request URL has to end with `/` or a file extension, then the servletcontainer won't 302 redirect to the path root or the welcome file.